# MemCacheError: execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I'm using the awesome cache-money gem with a large rails project. I frequently get these exceptions

> MemCache::MemCacheError: execution expired"

There doesn't seem to be a rhyme nor  reason. 
What *exactly* does this mean, and how to fix?

EDIT:

Here is a representative stack trace:

```
lib/authenticated_system.rb:100:in `login_from_session'
lib/authenticated_system.rb:12:in `current_user'
lib/authenticated_system.rb:6:in `logged_in?'
lib/authenticated_system.rb:35:in `authorized?'
lib/authenticated_system.rb:53:in `login_required'
```

The line in question is from RESTful_Authentication:

```
self.current_user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

Comment: Do you have a callstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Michael Simons](http://info.michael-simons.eu/) answered my question via his [blog post](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2009/03/23/phusion-passenger-and-memcache-client-revisited/). In essence, this is a [known problem](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_example_1_memcached_connection_sharing_harmful) that exists between Passenger and Memcached.

Here was Michael's fix:

```
# environment.rb
begin
   PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
     if forked
       # We're in smart spawning mode, so...
       # Close duplicated memcached connections - they will open themselves
       CACHE.reset
     end
   end
# In case you're not running under Passenger (i.e. devmode with mongrel)
rescue NameError => error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've heard through teammates that Rails' default memcache client does not attempt to automatically reconnect to the memcache daemon if for some reason it stops and restarts, though I haven't confirmed it myself. The [fiveruns memcache-client](http://github.com/fiveruns/memcache-client/tree/master) library fixes this issue.